# RoutingError when running rails app on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my rails app to `AWS`, but somehow only the default welcome page works (the one that shows "You are riding ruby on rails!") and all other pages don't work. Then I just created the most basic app following the instructions in AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)
and inspected the logfile. When I click on "About your application's environment", the logfile logs:

```
Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 24.6.158.239 at 2013-06-30 05:39:22 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/rails/info/properties"):
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'

actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'

railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'

railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'

activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'

railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'

actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'

rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'

rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'

activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'

rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'

rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'

rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'

rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'

rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'

rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'

railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'

railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'

...
```

However, this link works on my local machine. I have no idea why this happens and I don't know if this relates to the error when I deployed my own rails app to AWS...Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails disables this route in `production` mode. Either run the app in `development` mode or set an appropriate root route to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Also I found out that the other problem was caused by some bug in my code :)